# what is the replacement for HttpListener?

Tags: .net, webdav, httplistener

Yes, this is similar to [Is HttpListener class deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874466/is-httplistener-class-deprecated/12874642) and [Alternative to HttpListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280690/alternative-to-httplistener).

However, I'm looking for a out-of-the-box Microsoft supported alternative using .NET 4.5.1 (Visual Studio 2013) on Windows 8.1.  WCF doesn't really work as I want to support a custom HTTP protocol (actually, WebDAV; but that's custom as far as WCF is concerned.)

Is there anything, or do I have to use a Kayak or Firefly (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12878057/8877) answer)?  And the C# Webserver project (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729431/8877) answer) has been replaced with [Griffen.Framework](https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.framework).

Comment: I believe self-hosted OWIN is the direction.